# How to inherit STATIC methods?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I have a class

```
function Man(){...}

Man.drinkBeer = function(){...}
```

I need to inherit `SuperMan` from `Man`. And I still want my `Superman` be able to drink some beer.

How can I do that?

Comment: `Man.prototype.drinkBeer` is just as static as `Man.drinkBeer`....

Comment: No, you wrong. that's an example http://plnkr.co/edit/0ZdWIyergvNL0vW38ft9?p=preview

Comment: @Neal no, it isn't - the former only applies to instances.

Comment: @Alnitak If you don't like beer, then you just no need to call this function =)

Comment: But it's static - I _can't_ chose who to call it for!

Comment: First of all, you don't have a class. You have a function `Man` that uses syntactic sugar that makes it look like a constructor for a type of object. All the answers below you talk about is making the function SuperMan inherit from the function Man - it's very likely that that's not what you want. Speaking of which - statics are horrible for anything but constants/config.

Answer (score 6):

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(SuperMan, Man);
```

This will set the internal `__proto__` property of your derived function to be the base function.
Therefore, the derived function will inherit all properties from the base function.

Note that this affects the functions themselves, not their `prototype`s.

Yes, it's confusing.

No existing browser supports `setPrototypeOf()`; instead, you can use the non-standard (but working) alternative:

```
SuperMan.__proto__ = Man;
```

Comment: That's an ES6 method, isn't it?

Comment: Will that approach also inherit non static methods?

Comment: You just call it as `Parent.method()` or `Child.method()` - the same function appears as a property of both "class" functions.

Comment: @SLaks actually, the TC39 eventually decided _against_ `setPrototypeOf` and for `__proto__` (because of current browsers, and mainly because it's already used in Zepto which is widely deployed in websites running on mobile so it's de-facto standard). So `__proto__` is standard in ES6 and setPrototypeOf is still being considered. That said, `__proto__` and setPrototypeOf are both equally horrible.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`CoffeeScript`](http://coffeescript.org/) does for [class inheritance](http://coffeescript.org/#classes):

```
var __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function (child, parent) {
        for (var key in parent) {
            if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
        }
        function ctor() {
            this.constructor = child;
        }
        ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new ctor();
        child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
        return child;
    };
```

And they use it like so:

```
var Man = (function(){
    function Man() { ... }
    ...
    return Man;
})();
....
var SuperMan = (function(_super){
    __extends(SuperMan, _super);
    function SuperMan() { ... }
    ...
    return SuperMan;
})(Man);
....
```